# Energy and Time Signals

Tags: signal-power, signal-energy

In Signal Processing, we broadly categorize signals as either being "Energy Signals" or "Power Signals". If the total Energy for a signal is finite, we categorize it as a **Energy Signal**. Otherwise when the total Energy of the signal is infinite, if the total Power of the signal is finite, we categorize it as a **Power Signal**. What if both the total Energy and total Power of the signal is infinite, do we have a similar categorization for that case beyond describing it as an unstable or unbounded signal? Is there a similar normalization we can do to go beyond Power Signals and quantify another measure of the "amount" of the signal for those cases?

**Background:**
The total Energy for a generalized continuous-time complex signal $x(t)$ or discrete-time complex signal $x[n]$ is defined as:

$$ E = \int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}|x(t)|^2dt = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|x[n]|^2 \tag{1}\label{1}$$

This provides us with a convenient measure for the "amount" of a signal regardless of actual units for continuous time $x(t)$ or discrete time $x[n]$. When $x$ is an electrical signal in units of voltage in volts or current in amperes, and time in seconds, then we can associate $E$ with the total energy in Joules that would be dissipated by the voltage across or current through a 1 ohm resistor (one Joule is 1A through a 1 ohm resistor for 1 second). For purposes of signal processing, an "**Energy Signal**" is $x(t)$ and $x[n]$ in any units of magnitude versus time where equation \ref{1} converges, and the result of equation \ref{1} would be the total Energy. This would include any signals of finite duration in time and signals that decay with time and gives us a convenient measure for the "amount" of the signal. As a resulting vector magnitude, we would use $\sqrt{E}$, and to express in dB we would use $10\log_{10}(E)$.

For signals that don't decay and are not time limited (constant for all time, such as a sine wave extending from $t= -\infty$ to $t= +\infty$), equation \ref{1} does not converge and so we need another metric for these cases for the "amount" of the signal. Here we introduce the "**Power Signal**" where if we describe the signal instead as a "density" versus time, the result will converge in this case:

$$ P =  \lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{t=-T/2}^{+T/2}|x(t)|^2dt = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2N+1}\sum_{n=-N}^{N}|x[n]|^2 \tag{2}\label{2}$$

And thus to bring this back to the equivalent electrical signal, the Power is in units of Watts and is specifically the energy over time, or Joules/second. A Watt-Second is one Joule. A Kilowatt-Hour is Energy as 3.6 million Joules.

So in this interest of classifying all signals, what then do we call a signal when equation $\ref{2}$ doesn't converge? For example $x(t) = e^{at}$ when $\text{Real}\{a\}>1$ for $t \in [-\infty:\infty]$? We normalized equation \ref{1} through the use of equation \ref{2} and came up with another term to measure the "amount" of the signal. Is there then yet another normalization that is done with yet another unit of measure for the "amount" of signals where the Power is also infinite?

Comment: Personally I'd call them "pain in the neck"  :-) like acoustic feedback or the output of an unstable filter. Since the power is bounded by $P  <= x_{max}^2$, infinite power requires infinite amplitude (somewhere) which, of course, physical impossible. I'm not sure there is practical application for this type of signal.

Comment: @Hilmar yes exactly. That is actually part of my question that I should include-- what would be the practical application for such a signal?  It does show up as the impulse response of realizable unstable systems that we wrap with a controller, it also shows up equivalently as any system with poles in the right half plane

Comment: _Superpower signals_ comes to mind as an appropriate designation :-)

Comment: @DilipSarwate I like that! Come up with a normalization formula and provide it as an answer and it will be, at least until a better answer comes along.  I will link this when I refer to "superpower signals" in use cases. Hmmm I wonder if there is any physical units as well transitioning from Joules to Watts to Dilips????

Comment: I think superpower signals have not been defined (so far, waiting for Dilip to do it :-) because they don't have any use. Power signals don't exist in reality but they are useful when modeling e.g. white noise. What process is there whose model would benefit from superpower signals?

Comment: @MBaz If you build it, they will come!! :)

Comment: What you actually intended is, what if a rate of change of power exists for signal? That too $\frac{dP}{dt}$ is positive? Of course that kind of signals exist in physics. One example i can think of is shockwaves.

Comment: @MBaz Power signals don't exist in reality but they are useful when modeling ? Then how come 230V utility power reaches your home? They do exist in reality and they are not just philosophical gibberish.

Comment: @abhilash I believe it is because you are using a very different definition of Power Signal. Specific to this site, and the signal processing field, it has a very different meaning than utility power. I define power and energy signals (in this context) in the question.

Comment: @DanBoschen, ok it may not fall under definition of signal in the sense they do not carry any information. But they are also signal. Atleast you may find signal which may fall under book-ish definition of signal can have $\frac{dP}{dt}$ non zero.

Comment: @abhilash As Dan said, you're using a different definition of "power signal". In signal processing, a power signal has infinite energy and finite power. No physical signal can have infinite energy. This has nothing to do with the information a signal may or may not be carrying.